# "Api execution successful. No data found for the API."

Tags: yodlee

"Api execution successful. No data found for the API."

I am a customer of yodlee using live API .

In /jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/getAllSiteAccounts, i am passing both valid cobSessionToken, userSessionToken but it is returning "Api execution successful. No data found for the API." as response.

Shall i know what is wrong in my input.

Comment: appreciate if you could share the calling code?

Comment: I am getting this in both "getItemSummaries" , "getAllSiteAccount" API call. Is this related to refresh process or any restriction of hiting this url for limit no of times per day like that ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHP - REST API.

GET_ALL_SITE_ACCOUNTS = /jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/getAllSiteAccounts

$config = array(
        "url" => Yodlee\ConfigInc\serviceBaseUrl.Yodlee\ConfigInc\GET_ALL_SITE_ACCOUNTS,
        `"parameters" => array(
                        "cobSessionToken" =>  $cobSessionToken,
                        "userSessionToken" => $userSessionToken,
                )`
        );
$response_to_request   = Yodlee\restClient::Post($config["url"], $config["parameters"]);

so my $response_to_request variable returning "Api execution successful. No data found for the API."

Comment: If you have accounts added for the particular site and you still dont see them then you may perhaps verify if your server is white listed for Yodlee's service. If you've verified everything at your side then raising a service request to Yodlee would only help. you can refer to https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllSiteAccounts for clarification on the same

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your input. Your user doesn't have any data present in Yodlee's data base and hence this response is returned. You need to first add a site using bank credentials and then you will have data through these APIs.

Please refer to [Quick Start](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_REST_Quick_Start_Guide) guide for more help.